# Overlaying text with the picture environment

Tags: picture-mode

I use the picture environment to add some rotated text to the right at several places throughout my document. Obviously this affects the positioning of the text that follows. I would like to avoid this behaviour. That this, the text that follows should be placed exactly as if I had not written some text to the right. MWE below, I'm happy to use another method if needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,color,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}

\section{Section title}

\begin{picture}(40,40)(-280,-80)
\put(0,0){\rotatebox{-30}{\color{red}\large\textbf{CONTENT}}}
\end{picture}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I run your example I get an error: `! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \setbox 
l.9 \section{Section title}\rightcont
`

Comment: @Marijn Hm, strange, I don't (and I just copied the code once more from tex.stackexchange.com), I use TeX Live 2021.

Comment: I tried with TeX Live 2019 and 2020 (don't have 2021 here) which both fail with all compilers (latex, pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex) - but apparently it worked in the answer of campa below so it is probably an issue on my end :)

Comment: @Marijn Thanks! It also doesn't work on Overleaf. So it appears to be a 2021 vs before issue. I'll adjust the code.

Comment: @Marijn picture mode was extended in the latex 2020-10-01 Release so a fully updated texlive 2020 or texlive 2021 is needed

Comment: You can overlap anything using \smash, \raisebox, \rlap and \llap, but you need to know how far to move it from your starting point.